# Is there a symbol, or abbreviation for coefficient of x

Tags: notation

Doing some binomial expansions with algebra where I need to equate different coefficients together but don't know what to write:

[Coefficient of $x^3$] = *_*

$k=+1.5$

Answer (score 3):

For an expression $f(x)$, there is the notation $$[x^3](f(x))$$ See [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CoefficientNotation.html). This notation is verbose but can be useful for expressions in several variables.

For an expression in a single variable, I'd go for something simpler, like $$[f(x)]_3$$
but be explicit when you introduce or use non-standard notation.

Comment: Why do you think it is verbose? Anyway, it is quite useful for single-variable series as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just something like $a_{xn}$? Where *x* is the variable name and *n* the exponent. This seems to me more easy that the one given by @lhf.

You need to define the notation explicitly anyway and seems that no "standard" notation exist for this.